# Word Add-in Search Forever Loop

Tags: c#, ms-word

it is my first time asking a question here so here it goes:

I'm searching for text in a word document that has a "Heading 1" or "Heading 2" style name. Once found, I set a new range to the start of that text and the end of the document and call a method that finds the first table in that range and numbers column 1 if column two has text. Now my problem happens when my code finds the first record that matches completely. Everything works, but the Find.Execute goes into a forever loop and keeps finding the same text over and over. I want it to continue searching until the end of the document. Here is my code and thanks in advance:

```
    public void TextFind(object findText, string reqCode)
    {
        Document doc = Application.ActiveDocument;
        Range docRange = doc.Sections[1].Range;
        var intCount = 0;
        docRange.SetRange(0, docRange.Characters.Count);
        if (findText == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("findText");
        docRange.Find.Execute(findText, Forward: true, Wrap: WdFindWrap.wdFindStop);
        while (docRange.Find.Found)
        {
            intCount++;
            Style style = docRange.get_Style();
            var styleName = style.NameLocal;
            if (styleName == "Heading 1" || styleName == "Heading 2")
            {
                var endRange = doc.Sections[1].Range;
                var docRange2 = docRange;
                docRange2.SetRange(docRange.Start, endRange.End);
                ApplyNumberingToTable(docRange2, reqCode);
            }
            docRange.Find.Execute(findText, Forward: true, Wrap: WdFindWrap.wdFindStop);
        }

        MessageBox.Show(intCount.ToString());
    }
```

The `intCount` and `MessageBox` was an attempt to diagnose the problem by me.

Try number two consisted of:

So I am still stuck and I have tried to add the searched range to a List, and run a foreach on the List, but everytime the range changes the reference to that range in the list changes as well. I cannot for the life of me figure out how t5o instantiate the Range inside my while loop. Here is my code:

```
public void TextFind(object findText, string reqCode)
    {
        Document doc = Application.ActiveDocument;
        Range docRange = doc.Sections[1].Range;
        var intCount = 0;
        if (findText == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("findText");
        var rangelist = new List<Range>();
        var i = 0;
        while (docRange.Find.Execute(findText, Forward: true, Wrap: WdFindWrap.wdFindStop))
        {
            rangelist = new List<Range> {docRange};
            intCount++;
        }
        foreach ( var range in rangelist)
        {
            Style style = range.get_Style();
            var styleName = style.NameLocal;
            if (styleName != "Heading 1" && styleName != "Heading 2") continue;
            var endRange = doc.Sections[1].Range;
            range.SetRange(range.Start, endRange.End);
            ApplyNumberingToTable(range, reqCode);
        }
        if (intCount == 0) return;
        MessageBox.Show(rangelist.ToString());
    }
```

**Still looking for fix to this.
Thanks,**

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.find.execute.aspx), the method itself returns a boolean on whether or not it has suceeded in finding the search. Perhaps you should capture this variable and use that for you while statement as opposed to the Found property. I cannot currently test this; will return back with results later today.

Perhaps try:

```
        while (docRange.Find.Execute(findText, Forward: true, Wrap: WdFindWrap.wdFindStop))
        {
            intCount++;
            Style style = docRange.get_Style();
            var styleName = style.NameLocal;
            if (styleName == "Heading 1" || styleName == "Heading 2")
            {
                var endRange = doc.Sections[1].Range;
                var docRange2 = docRange;
                docRange2.SetRange(docRange.Start, endRange.End);
                ApplyNumberingToTable(docRange2, reqCode);
            }
            docRange.Find.Execute(findText, Forward: true, Wrap: WdFindWrap.wdFindStop);
        }
```

Comment: I tried that, but to no avail. The find.execute in the loop skips the second result, which in my test in a string with Heading 1 styling. If I remove that find.execute the loop still hangs up on the first result that satisfies the if statement. Would storing all of the ranges that work in an array and then calling ApplyNumberingToTable on each range in the array possibly work?